# ModelVisual 3D shows my image upside down, how can I make it proper?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, 3d

kI am creating a wpf application where I have written following xaml:

```
                     <ModelVisual3D>
                        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            <GeometryModel3D>
                                <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <MeshGeometry3D
                                         TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,4,5 "
                                         Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 "
                                         TextureCoordinates="0,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,0 "
                                         Positions="-0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 " />
                                </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                                <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <MaterialGroup>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="img8.png"></ImageBrush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </MaterialGroup>
                                </GeometryModel3D.Material>

                                <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                                    <RotateTransform3D>
                                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                            <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="MyAngleRotation" Axis="0,3,0" Angle="40" />
                                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    </RotateTransform3D>
                                </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                            </GeometryModel3D>
                        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    </ModelVisual3D>
```

It is working fine except it is showing image upside down as shown below:

[image: Current Image]

[image]

Can anybody help me how can I make it look proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a ScaleTransform as RenderTransform with X:1.0 and Y:-1.0 to the parent container that contains your model. Don't forget to set the RenderTransformOrigin-property to "0.5,0.5".